# Finding SNR and SNDR/SINAD from FFT of ADC

Tags: adc

I have a question about the FFT spectrum of an ADC output
[image]

I understand SFDR you can measure the difference between the fundamental and the next biggest spur/harmonic.

But how do you find SNDR from the plot? Can I simply just measure the fundamental to noise-floor differene? 
Similarly, how do I find SNR?

Comment: One piece of information missing : the number of FFT bins (or conversely, the width of each one). You can see there's "about" -70dB energy per bin ... you need to sum that across all bins. (Or convert to voltage/rtHz, and intecrate across 90MHz, etc)

Answer (score 0):

with no obvious spurs, how to proceed?

I'd expect 2*input - Fsample.

Thus 2*76 - fsample of 180 === 152 -180 = 28MHz.

Yet at 28MHz, there is a big dip